# how to fill foreign key column in one of the Django model/table with the value of parent table?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model/SQL table, which is static and will always have 4 rows with one column (ID) as primary key, like below

```
Status_ID  Status 
1          active
2          inactive
3          pending
4          deprecated
```

I have another Django model in which records will be inserted on daily basis and have foreign key (Status_ID) of above table and has to be inserted with status_ID as 2, always.

```
ID My_code     status_ID Location
1   some code  2         India
2   other code 2         USA
```

I have below code which populates the second table

```
T1= Table2(My_code='some code', Location='India')
T1.save()
```

what should be the piece of line to populate second table's status_ID column with 2, always ?

Model definations are as follows :-

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    Status_ID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Table1'


Class Table2(models.Model):
    ID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    My_code=models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    status_ID=models.ForeignKey('Table1', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    Location=models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Table2'
```

Comment: Where are your models definitions ? Note that this is documented anyway, and quite easy to test by yourself (both of which - looking up the doc and testing in your shell - takes less time than posting here).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have added model definitions, can you please point me to the place in official doc where i can lookup ? I couldn't find a scenario which is like mycase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
status = Table1.objects.get(Status="active")
T1= Table2(My_code='some code', Location='India', status_ID=status)
T1.save()
```

Comment: simple.How can I overlook this. worked for me. Thanks.